# Во всех проектах AnonymousUser. Django

Tags: javascript, python, sql, django

Я понятия не имею, что сделал не так, но у меня абсолютно во всех проектах теперь request.user отправляет AnonymousUser, несмотря на то, что как минимум admin существует. Не подскажите в чем может быть проблема?
Да и дело в том, что иногда работает как надо, а иногда выдает AnonymousUser. В инете не могу найти ответов.
Кучу раз уже удалял django из venv. Удалял все библиотеки, чтобы не было конфликта. Убирал даже все расширения в браузере, быть может js мешает. Ничего не помогает

Comment: Давайте начнём с очевидного вопроса: а почему вы решили, что там должно быть что-то другое?

Comment: @andreymal, потому что, если войти в админку, например, то при request.user будет выходить username админа в консоль, который является Simplelazyobject, которого можно будет вытащить из модели User. В моем случае в консоль выводит AnonymousUser, с помощью которого нельзя получить пользователя из бд, ведь выходит ошибка, что id ожидает число.

Comment: Что конкретно означает «войти в админку» — как вы входите в админку и какой ответ прилетает от сервера в момент входа?

Comment: @andreymal, захожу на http://localhost:8000/admin. Вхожу в админку(логин: admin). Теперь, заходя на другие страницы, то есть, обрабатывая другие шаблоны, я, по идее, получаю в консоли при print(request.user) слово 'admin'. Но такого не происходит, а вижу я в консоли только AnonymousUser. При попытке создать пост Post.objects.create(user=request.user ...) я получаю ошибку, что поле id ожидает число, а не SimpleLazyObject. Это поведение ненормально, ведь весь прошлый месяц я спокойно мог создавать посты без этой ошибки. Я не понимаю, почему именно сейчас это происходит.Ине только в одном проекте

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос — какой конкретно ответ от сервера прилетает в момент входа? Прежде чем заходить на другие страницы, нужно сперва разобраться со входом

Comment: Распишу чуть подробнее — в момент входа важно проверить следующие вещи: 1) Точно ли вход вообще успешен? (юзер есть, пароль верный и т.п.); 2) Точно ли сервер создал и прислал сессионную куку? 3) Точно ли присланная кука привязана к правильному домену и правильному пути и не истекла? 4) Точно ли браузер вообще сохранил сессионную куку и будет использовать в последующих запросах? 5) Точно ли сервер сохранил сессию в своей базе данных и не стёр её от истечения срока годности?

Comment: @andreymal, из всего сказанного вами, я понимаю только пункт 1. Да, пароль верный, юзер есть, в бд все отображается. Честно не знаю, как проверить сессионные куки(да и где они вообще?). Если это все слишком долго разбирать, то было бы неплохо хотя бы ссылки на информацию об этом. Сам разберусь может.